# How to prevent multi match with regex only betwen [ ]

Tags: regex, flutter

I have an exeption in a regex. With this regex

https://regex101.com/r/pxTfci/1

I can match all data (key:value) from a string separate by `,`  . Problem I have a conflict with some List who is formatted like that

Mylist:[data1, data2, data3]

With this regex `(?<=(?<!: *)\[).*?(?=, )|(?<=, +(?=[^ \r\n]))(?:.*?(?=, )|[^\r\n\[\]]+?(?=\])|[^\r\n]+\](?= *\]))`

I have 3 match

```
match 1 = Mylist:[data1
match 2 = data2
match 3 = data3]
```

I search for this exeption, when I have `[` `]` , to have in output `Mylist:[data1, data2, data3]`

I don't know if it's possible. here is an exemple of complet input format

```
MyString=[XXXXXX:XX   XX   XX   XX, XXXXX:332.83, XXXXX:XXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX, XXXX:0.0, XXXX:2, XXXX:0, XXXX:-256, XXXX:5, XXXX:136935, XXXX:0, XXXX:XX XXX XXX, XXXX:0.5, XXXXX:true, XXXX:0.509375, XXX:0.0, 2022-09-17,XXXXX:1, list1:[2000-00-00 00:00, 2022-11-16 15:29, 2022-11-16 15:29], list2:[2000-00-00 00:00, 2022-11-16 15:29, 2022-11-16 15:29], ]
```

I search to have

```
match 1 = XXXXXX:XX   XX   XX   XX
match 2 = XXXXX:332.83
...
match x =2022-09-17,XXXXX:1
match y =list1:[2000-00-00 00:00, 2022-11-16 15:29, 2022-11-16 15:29]
match z =list2:[2000-00-00 00:00, 2022-11-16 15:29, 2022-11-16 15:29]
```

Comment: Long story short, recursive data structures such as yours can't be parsed by pure regex. There are implementations that support recursion, but using it for parsing of complex data creates a maintenance liability of epic proportions. The thing you parse looks like JSON, see if you can use a pre-built parser for it. Otherwise, I recommend writing a tiny recursive descent parser: it does not take long, the result is easy to read, and a skill you develop as part of the "exercise" is incredibly useful. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

Firstly try something like this :

```
List<String> listString = [];
                String MyString =
                    "[XXXXXX:XX   XX   XX   XX, XXXXX:332.83, XXXXX:XXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX, XXXX:0.0, XXXX:2, XXXX:0, XXXX:-256, XXXX:5, XXXX:136935, XXXX:0, XXXX:XX XXX XXX, XXXX:0.5, XXXXX:true, XXXX:0.509375, XXX:0.0, 2022-09-17,XXXXX:1, list1:[2000-00-00 00:00, 2022-11-16 15:29, 2022-11-16 15:29], list2:[2000-00-00 00:00, 2022-11-16 15:29, 2022-11-16 15:29], ]";
                String newString = MyString.substring(1, MyString.length - 1);
                bool save = true;
                int start = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < newString.length; i++) {
                  if (newString[i] == "," && save) {
                    listeString.add(newString.substring(start, i));
                    start = i + 1;
                  } else if (newString[i] == "[") {
                    save = false;
                  } else if (newString[i] == "]") {
                    save = true;
                  }
                }
```

or

When you create your string, you replace your "," in your lists with a special character that you can easily change.

Have a good day

Comment: Can you create a new list by grouping these two items that will always appear in the same place? 
Without a real example of your string, I can't give you a better solution